# Help solving trigonometric equation $\cos^2(x) - \sin(x) = 0$ within the domain $[0, 2\pi]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I‘m trying to solve some trig equations and I‘m having some difficulties....

> within the domain $[0,2\pi]$
>
> $\cos^2(x)-\sin(x)=0$

I didn't get very far here, I figured it would be the same as writing $1-\sin^2(x)-\sin(x)=0$. Also, I tried to factor a bunch of combinations but nothing really seemed to make it clearer.

I‘m not sure how to proceed. Help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: use that $$\cos(x)^2=1-\sin(x)^2$$ and solve the quadratic. Then we Substitute $$t=\sin(x)$$ so $$t^2+t-1=0$$
By the quadratic formula we get
$$t_{1,2}=-\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Comment: Actually, its one of the things that I did, but how do I convert that answer which I assumed to be wrong into the domain [0.2pi]?

Comment: @user549904 Can you see why the solutions are $\theta,\,\pi-\theta$ with $\theta:=\arcsin\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$?

Comment: Not really.. I mean I know a full circle of cosine and sine is 2pi. So adding and subtracting two pi is familiar, but I‘m not sure what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You're right with saying that
$$1-\sin^2(x)-\sin(x)=0$$
Then $$\sin^2(x)+\sin(x)-1=0$$
Let $\sin(x)=s$, then:
$$s^2+s-1=0$$
$$s=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+4}}{2}=-\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt5}{2}$$

$$\sin(x)=-\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt5}{2}\to x=\sin^{-1}\bigg(-\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt5}{2}\bigg)$$
$$x\approx0.6662, \pi-0.6662\to x\approx0.6662, 2.4754.$$

You can use the $\sin(x)$ graph [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2h04xwra0j) to see that.

$\sin(x)=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt5}{2}$ has no solutions because $-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt5}{2}<-1$

Comment: Isn't that the arcsin of the golden ratio(s)?

Comment: Hey thanks, but would you know how to convert that answer within the [0,2pi] domain? I‘m supposed to get an answer of $1pi/6$, $5pi/6$ and $3pi/2$

Comment: I've done them in the $[0,2\pi]$ domain. Note that $\cos^{2}(\frac{\pi}{6})-\sin(\frac{\pi}{6})=\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}\ne 0$. Are you sure therefore that the question you've uploaded to us is correct?

Comment: @AndrewLi, typically the golden ratio $\phi$ is denoted by $\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Here we have the arcsin of $\phi-1$, if we take the $\pm$ as a $+$